# How to get new/updated records from Delta table after upsert using merge?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

Is there any way to get updated/inserted rows after [upsert using merge](https://docs.delta.io/0.4.0/delta-update.html#id4) to Delta table in spark streaming job?

```
val df = spark.readStream(...)
val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forName("...")


def upsertToDelta(events: DataFrame, batchId: Long) {

deltaTable.as("table")
    .merge(
      events.as("event"), 
      "event.entityId == table.entityId")
    .whenMatched()
        .updateExpr(...))
    .whenNotMatched()
      .insertAll()
    .execute()
}

df
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .foreachBatch(upsertToDelta _)
  .outputMode("update")
  .start()
```

I know I can create another job to read updates from the delta table. But is it possible to do the same job? From what I can see, [execute() returns Unit](https://docs.delta.io/0.4.0/delta-update.html#id4).

Comment: are you using Databricks' version of Delta, or Open source?

Comment: Databricks' version, @AlexOtt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable [Change Data Feed](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html) on the table, and then have another stream or batch job to fetch the changes, so you'll able to receive information on what rows has changed/deleted/inserted. It could be enabled with:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name SET TBLPROPERTIES (delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true)
```

if thable isn't registered, you can use path instead of table name:

```sql
ALTER TABLE delta.`path` SET TBLPROPERTIES (delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true)
```

The changes will be available if you add the `.option("readChangeFeed", "true")` option when reading stream from a table:

```
spark.readStream.format("delta") \
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
  .table("table_name")
```

and it will add three columns to table describing the change - the most important is `_change_type` (please note that there are two different types for update operation).

If you're worried about having another stream - it's not a problem, as you can run multiple streams inside the same job - you just don't need to use `.awaitTermination`, but something like `spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()` to wait on multiple streams.

P.S. But maybe this answer will change if you explain why you need to get changes inside the same job?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
I'm trying to get a job, which would 

a) create and maintain a CURRENT_ENTITY table using upserts. At any point in time, this table should contain the most recent version of ENTITY rows. 
b) create a history of every row in CURRENT_ENTITY table via getting inserts/updates history and writing them to append-only ENTITY_HISTORY table.

Comment: Delta Change Feed is exactly for that. You just need to have two streams - one for updating `CURRENT_ENTITY` as you have right now, and second, very simple readStream/writeStream that will read changeFeed & populate `ENTITY_HISTORY`

Comment: One more question - the second readStream will read a delta table which is being updated. So I'll have to set ignoreChanges = true, wouldn't it potentially result in receiving some events twice?

Comment: Should I also explicitly ensure that there are no duplicates in the history table?

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicates in the History table until you're replaying the same payload multiple times.  The only thing that you need to take into account is that for update there are two events: `update_preimage` and `update_postimage` (original & updated rows). So if you want to track only latest value, you need to have a filter like `_change_type <> 'update_preimage'`